# Android Emulator screen record using ADB commands not working in Mac stadium properly

Tags: macos, android-emulator

I am trying to record emulator video for Google mandate video submission by running UITests calling adb shell commands, when doing this in Mac mini, we are able to see generated video file without any issues. when trying this in Mac Stadium, we are facing issues like blank in some portion of video or sometimes we are not able to see full video as well. Not sure whether this is an infrastructure issue or is there any settings we need to configure in MAC, we tried to keep Sleep settings as NEVER and screensaver as disabled.